# How to consume a UDP stream of bytes using RX extensions in .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, udp, system.reactive, dispose

I've come up with this solution. ( Not tested yet ) via a lot of bouncing around on the web.

```
Private Function ObserveUDP() As IObservable(Of bytes())


    Dim f = Function(observer)
                Dim endpoint = New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(Me.IpAdress), Me.IPPort)
                Dim client = New UdpClient(endpoint)

                Dim obs = observable.*emphasized text*Generate(Of Task(Of UdpReceiveResult), UdpReceiveResult) _
                      ( Nothing _
                      , Function(task As Task(Of UdpReceiveResult)) task Is Nothing Or Not task.IsCompleted() _
                      , Function(task As Task(Of UdpReceiveResult)) client.ReceiveAsync() _
                      , Function(task As Task(Of UdpReceiveResult)) task.Result)

                Dim observable = obs.Select(Function(r) r.Buffer)

                dim handle = observable.Subscribe(observer)

                Dim df = Sub() 
                    client.Close()
                    handle.Dispose()
                End Sub

                Return Disposable.Create(df)

    End Function

    Return observable.Create(f)

End Function
```

My requirement was to make sure the UDP client is closed when the subscription is droppped. I'm pretty sure the above code is close but I think it's not quite right. Any input would be appreciated.

*** EDIT ***

Actually the above example is totally wrong and will just create a large number of task objects synchronously
but not await them. After a bit of trial and error I've come up with the following generic function for
unfolding an awaitable which is called over and over again. Any comments?

```
''' initializer - a function that initializes and returns the state object
''' generator   - a function that asynchronously using await generates each value
''' finalizer   - a function for cleaning up the state object when the sequence is unsubscribed

Private Function ObservableAsyncSeq(Of T, I)( _
    initializer As Func(Of I), _
    generator As Func(Of I, Task(Of T)), _
    finalizer As Action(Of I))  As IObservable(Of T)

    Dim q = Function(observer As IObserver(Of T))
                Dim go = True
                Try
                    Dim r = Async Sub()
                                Dim ii As I = initializer()
                                While go
                                    Dim result = Await generator(ii)
                                    observer.OnNext(result)
                                End While
                                finalizer(ii)
                                observer.OnCompleted()
                            End Sub
                    Task.Run(r)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    observer.OnError(ex)
                End Try

                ' Disposable for stopping the sequence as per
                ' the observable contract
                Return Sub() go = False

            End Function

    Return Observable.Create(q)
End Function
```

And example of use with UDP

```
Private Function ObserveMeasurementPoints2() As IObservable(Of ProcessedDate)
    Dim initializer = Function()
                          Dim endpoint = New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(Me.IpAdress), Me.IPPort)
                          Return New UdpClient(endpoint)
                      End Function

    Dim finalizer = Function(client As UdpClient)
                        client.Close()
                    End Function

    Dim generator = Function(client As UdpClient) As Task(Of UdpReceiveResult)
                        Return client.ReceiveAsync()
                    End Function

    Return ObservableAsyncSeq(initializer, generator, finalizer).Select(Function(r) ProcessBytes(r.Buffer))

End Function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use either `Observable.Using` as Enigmativity mentioned or simply use the regular `Observable.Create` method which accepts an `IDisposable` as a return argument - this is enough for safe disposal.

Using iterators or async is perfectly fine. I've listed a more Rx-ish way to do this:

```
Public Shared Function UdpStream(Of T)(endpoint As IPEndPoint, processor As Func(Of Byte(), T)) As IObservable(Of T)
    Return Observable.Using(Of T, UdpClient)(
        Function() New UdpClient(endpoint),
        Function(udpClient) _
            Observable.Defer(Function() udpClient.ReceiveAsync().ToObservable()) _
            .Repeat() _
            .Select(Function(result) processor(result.Buffer))
    )
End Function
```

Legacy way:

```
Public Shared Function UdpStream(Of T)(endpoint As IPEndPoint, processor As Func(Of Byte(), T)) As IObservable(Of T)
    Return Observable.Using(
        Function() New UdpClient(endpoint),
        Function(udpClient) Observable.Defer( _
        Observable.FromAsyncPattern(
            AddressOf udpClient.BeginReceive,
            Function(iar)
                Dim remoteEp = TryCast(iar.AsyncState, IPEndPoint)
                Return udpClient.EndReceive(iar, remoteEp)
            End Function)
        ).Repeat() _
         .Select(processor)
    )
End Function
```

Test:

```
Shared Sub Main()
    Using UdpStream(New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 13200),
                    Function(bytes) String.Join(",", bytes)
                    ).Subscribe(AddressOf Console.WriteLine)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Using

    Console.WriteLine("Done")
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

Comment: The above solution only gets a single result from the udp client. Also visual studio 2012 tells me that beingreceive and endreceive have been deprecated in favour of task based async methods.

Comment: I'm taking a bet that something like this works. Observable.Defer( () => udpclient.AsyncReceive().ToObservable() ).Repeat()

Comment: I see you use repeat in your solution as well.sorry I missed that on my first comment. However I think it is possible to use the task based observable generators to make the code cleaner.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing Yes. The old way is backwards compatible. I've added the new way as well.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `Observable.Using` - it is specifically used to create an observable that uses a disposable resource to generate its values and when completed it automatically disposes the resource.

You'll find that the `UdpClient` has identical `Close` & `Dispose` method implementations so you don't need to call `Close` if you call `Dispose`.

From reflector:

```
void IDisposable.Dispose()
{
    this.Dispose(true);
}

public void Close()
{
    this.Dispose(true);
}
```

Here's the signature for `Using`:

```
Public Shared Function Using(Of TSource, TResource As IDisposable)(
    ByVal resourceFactory As Func(Of TResource),
    ByVal observableFactory As Func(Of TResource, IObservable(Of TSource)))
        As IObservable(Of TSource)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not used the UDPClient before, but it appears that you are using Tasks (Cardinality =1) to try and receive streams of data (Cardinality = many). It seems to work around this you have slapped a repeat on your query. This means that your query will do this

1. Create a UDPClient
2. Invoke the request for data
3. Receive the first data it gets
4. push the data on the sequence
5. close the sequence
6. Dispose the UDPClient
7. Create a UDPClient (back to step 1)
8. Invoke the request for data
9. Receive the first data it gets
10. ....until you dispose the connection.

I think you should just be able to read off the socket/network connection by pulling in a stream of bytes. I show you how to do this in my blog post:

http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html#CreatingYourOwnIterator

This way you will just hold one connection open and push bytes as you receive them.

Having a quick google I also found that there were concerns about the reliability of the UDPClient implementation.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1938/Issues-with-UdpClient-Receive

HTH

Lee

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace MyLib
{
    public static class ObservableExtensions
    {
        //TODO: Could potentially upgrade to using tasks/Await-LC
        public static IObservable<byte> ToObservable(
            this Stream source,
            int buffersize,
            IScheduler scheduler)
        {
            var bytes = Observable.Create<byte>(o =>
            {
                var initialState = new StreamReaderState(source, buffersize);
                var currentStateSubscription = new SerialDisposable();
                Action<StreamReaderState, Action<StreamReaderState>> iterator =
                (state, self) =>
                    currentStateSubscription.Disposable = state.ReadNext()
                        .Subscribe(
                            bytesRead =>
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
                                {
                                    o.OnNext(state.Buffer[i]);
                                }
                                if (bytesRead > 0)
                                    self(state);
                                else
                                    o.OnCompleted();
                            },
                            o.OnError);
                var scheduledWork = scheduler.Schedule(initialState, iterator);
                return new CompositeDisposable(currentStateSubscription, scheduledWork);
            });
            return Observable.Using(() => source, _ => bytes);
        }

        private sealed class StreamReaderState
        {
            private readonly int _bufferSize;
            private readonly Func<byte[], int, int, IObservable<int>> _factory;
            public StreamReaderState(Stream source, int bufferSize)
            {
                _bufferSize = bufferSize;
                _factory = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<byte[], int, int, int>(
                source.BeginRead,
                source.EndRead);
                Buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            }
            public IObservable<int> ReadNext()
            {
                return _factory(Buffer, 0, _bufferSize);
            }
            public byte[] Buffer { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually you are wrong. If you look at Asti's answer it doesn't throw the UDPClient away on each repeat. It just call repeats ReceiveAsync over and over again. This is all wrapped with a Using operator which only disposes the UDP client at the end with the registration is dropped.

Comment: Beg your pardon, only scrolled up to the "Legacy way".